# Connecting Fingerprint sensor with arduino in VB6

Tags: vb6

How Can I Interface or Connect the fingerprint with arduino uno in vb6? I already enrolled it the arduino but my problem is that I need now to interface it in vb6 and I don't know-how.

```
Private Sub MSComm1_OnComm()
          MSComm1.PortOpen = True 
          MSComm1.RThreshold = 1 
          MSComm1.CommPort = 9 
          MSComm1.Settings = "9600,n,8,1"    
End Sub
```

That is the only thing that i know.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post code you have tried so far. How are you communicating from VB6 to the Arduino for example. We can help you if you provide more details.

Comment: Uhmm. This Is The Only Thing That I Know. @ÉtienneLaneville

Comment: Private Sub MSComm1_OnComm()
MSComm1.PortOpen = True
MSComm1.RThreshold = 1
MSComm1.CommPort = 9
MSComm1.Settings = "9600,n,8,1"

End Sub

Comment: Sorry This is my first time here in stackoverflow. so im nervous to ask question.

Comment: You can edit your question and add your code there along with any extra information you think can help us understand the problem. Please don't hesitate to ask for help, that's what these questions are for. Other users are here to help.

Comment: Just Like That @ÉtienneLaneville i hope you can help me\

Comment: i just want to know now the how can i interface my fingerprint sensor in the visual basic

Comment: Your first step is to establish communication with your device over the serial port. I imagine you can send it some commands and it will send back a response with a status of your command. Using @tcarvin's advice, look up "VB6 MSComm control examples" on Google. You can probably find information about Arduino serial interface on Google. Once you can get basic communication between the Arduino and your application going, you can look into requesting fingerprint data.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is really "How do I use the MSComm control" (and I kind of suspect that it is) then use that as your google search term.  I did and hit lots of samples.  Here is one of many:  http://www.ontrak.net/visual.htm

The core of it all is to use `MSComm.Output` to send data and `MSComm.Input` to receive data.

Stackoverflow is more intended for very specific question as opposed to large "how-to" question.  Feel free to refine your question or post new ones if you have a specific problem you run into.

Best of luck!